# Display Div relative to Href element

Tags: javascript

Need to position a div based on the href element position in the page.
The code which I currentl have works on my machine which runs IE8.
The same code does not work on another machine with same configuration . Please help

BTW , the div is absolutely position and in the javascript we have:

```
divobj.style.left = event.x - 185;
divobj.style.top = event.y - 5;
```

Comment: @JohnP, sorry for the unrelated question, but how do you have a properly formatted link in your comment, i can't find how to do it, i will delete this comment as soon as you tell me... and that i thank you

Comment: @Ibu: Start writing a comment and click  on the `help` link below the `Add Comment` button to see the syntax for various formatting options. It's just Markdown.

Comment: @Felix Thank you very much, it was write before my eyes and i never looked

Comment: @ibu just use this format `[Text](http://link/)`

Comment: Back to the original question - I've had a similar situation where 2 machines with IE8 display the same web app differently, just pay attention to what kind of compatibility mode the browser might be in. #OnlyIE

Answer (score 0):

try to use this function.

```
function getElementPosition(element) {
        var x = 0; var y = 0;
        while(element !=null    )   {
            x += element.offsetLeft || 0;
            y += element.offsetTop  || 0;
            element = element.offsetParent;
        if (!element || element.style['position'] == 'relative' || element.tagName == 'BODY') break;
        }
        return {'x':x, 'y':y};
    }
```

it will retrun the position of your link element, but you have to pass that element as argument to this function.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be as simple as adding a unit of measurement, e.g.:

```
divobj.style.left = event.x - 185 + 'px'; divobj.style.top = event.y - 5 + 'px';
```

Some browsers assume 'px' as the unit of measurement; others don't make an assumption and therefore do nothing with what they consider an invalid value.